# Form Inheritance in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a .php file, and a .html file.

Within a button click, I give a:href as registration.php. But the html is in new-registration.html.

I don't know how to link them? Like ASP.NET we write inherits, but what do I write in this? I want to see the html page.

I know it is really stupid but I don't know any PHP.

Basically, is there any form or page inheritance concept in PHP?

Comment: Are you looking for [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)? You can just include the .html into the .php and the HTML will be output directly...

Comment: Here's a link to an example from the php manual. This is a good reference and starting point. http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Comment: @DaveRandom add you comment as an answer, since it is one.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did it, however I got an error ) Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'new-registration.html' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\openx\www\admin\manual-registration.php on line 3 I hate openx btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net is a framework, rather than simply independent pages, as is the case with PHP.

PHP doesn't has any standard framework of template inheriting.

Some frameworks you should try which supports inheriting templates and better MVC approaches:

1. [Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) ([With some alterations](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/layout_library/))
2. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com)
3. [Symphony Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/) and [etc](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look up how HTML forms work:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

You could also google "html forms tutorial" and see what comes up.

I used Laura Lemay's book to learn HTML3 way back when I started. The new version has some HTML5 coverage and should (IMHO) be on any new developer's bookshelf.

[http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-Publishing-HTML/dp/0672330962/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325600704&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330962)

Basically your form's ACTION attribute will point to your PHP script and either GET or POST data to your PHP. GET appends the form fields in a querystring while POST passes the data behind the scenes. (I usually stick with POST for anything longer than a couple of fields)

Comment: w3schools is bad: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools is an awful place to learn, lots of newbies wind up asking questions here, confused because they learned HTML there. Try a more reputable site like http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// somewhere in registration.php
include 'new-registration.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your new-registration.html to .php file so new-registration.php and inside it above doc type include all your php

Example:

```
<?php
Your php here
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
.....
```

And than I assume you have a form where user inputs their info.

you could set its action to new-registration.php so it runs all the php on the page.

e.g. `<form action="new-registration.php"></form>`

Comment: My boss told me not to do that. I have to write them separately.

Comment: You can include different pages like this 
<?php includ_once("page.html"); ?> But this only works in .php pages

Answer (score 0):

1) If your file named new-registration.html and it contains the below form.

```
<form name="frmName" method="post" action="registration.php">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

From the action attribute you can navigate the page

2) Or simply `<a href="registration.php"> <input type="button" name="goto"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can write your code direct after out of php code like this

   Hello , and welcome
2. Load your code in  tag
3. Use Ajax to load HTML Page